# Extract a whole section from 1000 PDF files to Excel

Tags: python, excel

How to extract only section 5 from 1000 PDF files to excel.

Each PDF files would have 50 pages or over 100 pages.  Section 5 would have two lines or even up to several pages.  The unique identifier for section 5 would be started from title of Section 5 and ended before Section 6.  All those 1000 PDF files would be saved in one folder on desktop.

All text can be copy and paste and recognizable, no OCR is needed.

**PDF Files are in the following format.**

```
Section 1
xxxxx

Section 2
YYYY

Section 3
UUUUU

Section 4
OOOOO

Section 5
PPPPP
PPP
PPPP

Section 6
GGGG
```

**Result table is expected to be following format:**

```
| File Name | Section 5 |
| --------  | --------  |
| File 1    | P...      |
| File 2    | PP...     |
| File 3    | PPPP...   |
| File 4    | PP        |
....

| File 1000 | PPP...    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways to do this kind of thing. See the code below.

```
# Loop through all PDF files in a folder
# if your file names is like file1.pdf, file2.pdf, and ... then you may use a for loop:
import PyPDF2
import re

for k in range(1,100):
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Python/PDF Files/Loop Through Multiple PDF Files and Search For Specific Text in Each/pdf_files/file%s.pdf"%(k))

    # get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()

    # define keyterms
    String = "New York State Real Property Law"

    # extract text and do the search
    for i in range(0, NumPages):
        PageObj = object.getPage(i)
        print("this is page " + str(i)) 
        Text = PageObj.extractText() 
        # print(Text)
        ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
        print(ResSearch)


# Loop through all PDF files in a folder
# otherwise you can walk through your folder using the os module
import PyPDF2
import re
import os

for foldername,subfolders,files in os.walk(r"C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Python/PDF Files/Loop Through Multiple PDF Files and Search For Specific Text in Each/pdf_files/"):
    for file in files:
        # open the pdf file
        object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(os.path.join(foldername,file))

        # get number of pages
        NumPages = object.getNumPages()

        # define keyterms
        String = "New York State Real Property Law"

        # extract text and do the search
        for i in range(0, NumPages):
            PageObj = object.getPage(i)
            print("this is page " + str(i)) 
            Text = PageObj.extractText() 
            # print(Text)
            ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
            print(ResSearch)
```